# Try to curl and upload file to Shared Drive using GoogleDrive API V3

Tags: curl, google-drive-api

I was trying to upload my file to GoogleDrive with GoogleDrive API V3 by Curl. It worked fine in my own Drive but not when upload to my team's shared drive.
(Because some reason, I can only use the curl command.)

Here is my code:

```
    curl -X POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?&uploadType=multipart \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}" \
    -F "metadata=@metadata.txt;type=application/json;charset=UTF-8" \
    -F "file=@test.zip"
```

And here is my meta file

```
    {
    "name": "test.zip",
    "parents": ["MY ID TO FOLDER IN SHARED DRIVE"],
    "description": "aa",
    }
```

but it's return error like this

```
    {
     "error": {
      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound",
        "message": "File not found: MY ID TO FOLDER IN SHARED DRIVE.",
        "locationType": "parameter",
        "location": "fileId"
       }
      ],
      "code": 404,
      "message": "File not found: MY ID TO FOLDER IN SHARED DRIVE."
     }
    }
```

Can any one tell me what going wrong?
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified curl command:

```
curl -X POST "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&supportsAllDrives=true" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}" \
-F "metadata=@metadata.txt;type=application/json;charset=UTF-8" \
-F "file=@test.zip"
```

- `supportsAllDrives=true` is added. I thought that the reason of `File not found: MY ID TO FOLDER IN SHARED DRIVE` is due to this. And also, the URL is enclosed by `"`.

#### Modified metadata:

```
{
  "name": "test.zip",
  "parents": ["MY ID TO FOLDER IN SHARED DRIVE"],
  "description": "aa"
}
```

- `,` of `"description": "aa",` is removed.

#### Note:

- This modified curl command supposes that your access token can be used for uploading the file. Please be careful this.
- When you have no write permission for the folder of `"MY ID TO FOLDER IN SHARED DRIVE"`, this modified curl command cannot be used. So please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

Comment: wow thanks ! It worked !
I've tried supportsAllDrives property too but still went wrong before. It seems like I made so many mistakes! Thanks very much!

Comment: @Apple Love Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.